# How to find .bashrc or .zshrc?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, homebrew

I just got a MacBook Pro and am in the process of trying to get GNU commands installed. I'm following [this](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/) guide, but I don't know how to do:

Then add the following line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

I did a `cd; ls -a` and I don't see any files called `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Additional Info: 
Running Yosemite 10.10.3 on a MacBook Pro. Already have Xcode installed. Total newbie at this.

Answer (score 17):

To know which shell are you using, use the following command:

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

It will return something like:

```
/bin/bash
```

or

```
/bin/zsh
```

After you know the shell, if the file `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` doesn't exist in your home directory (`echo $HOME` to find out), just create it.

If you are using `bash`, you may have a file called `.bash_profile` where you can put your `export` command instead (don't know in `zsh`).

Comment: Mine returns to /bin/bash, but I don't have a .bashrc. How and where do I create it? I do remember seeing a .bash_profile somewhere after doing 'ls -a' but I don't remember how I got there

Comment: @TommyK create it in your user dir, using `touch ~/.bashrc`

Comment: vscode adds something to the PATH, but I didn't see the file `.zshrc`, so which file did it modify?

Answer (score 0):

Create your .bashrc with your text editor & add any files you want. Go to terminal and type in: ls -a   It will show some hidden files.